# Is Siavash an islamic name?

Tags: naming

I named my baby after the Iranian prince Siavash but friends keep telling me that it's not a Muslim name and doesn't have a good meaning.

Can you guide me on this?

Comment: There's no such thing as an Islamic name.

Answer (score 1):

If you define Islamic name as one which has its origin in Islamic scripture, tradition or association with significant persons (like the names Ibrahim, Yusuf, Musa, Abdullah, Muhammad, Abu Bakr, Umar, Usman, Ali, Hassan, Hussain). Then Siavash is not an Islamic name.

If you mean a name that is in use by Muslims as part of their culture, then it is an Islamic name as it is used by Persian Muslims.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a bad meaning. It means 'owner of a glorious black horse'. do you know the legend of Siavash? He was a very good fair person that a woman accuse him falsely and to prove his Innocent He crossed the fire and didn't burn. He crossed the fire with a black horse. there's a special Ceremony that the people of 'Siavoshan', an old village with Rich History, hold every year to honor him. He is a respectful character and your child bear the name of a hero.